# Running several ApplicationSessions non-blockingly using autbahn.asyncio.wamp

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, autobahn, wamp-protocol

I'm trying to run two `autobahn.asyncio.wamp.ApplicationSession`s in python at the same time. Previously, I did this using a modification of the autobahn library as suggested in [this post's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38298548/multiple-thread-with-autobahn-applicationrunner-and-applicationsession). I now
require a bit more professional solution.

After googling about for a while, [this post appeared quite promising](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28414302/how-create-a-python-application-with-two-thread-each-which-has-a-autobahn-applic), but uses the `twisted` library, instead of `asyncio`. I wasn't able to identify a similar solution for the `asyncio` branch of the `autobahn` library, since it doesn't appear to be using `Reactors`.

The main problem I have, is that `ApplicationRunner.run()` is blocking (which is why I previously outsourced it to a thread), so I can't just run a second `ApplicationRunner` after it.

I do need to access 2 websocket channels at the same time, which I cannot appear to do with a single `ApplicationSession`.

My Code so far:

```
from autobahn.asyncio.wamp import ApplicationSession
from autobahn.asyncio.wamp import ApplicationRunner
from asyncio import coroutine
import time


channel1 = 'BTC_LTC'
channel2 = 'BTC_XMR'

class LTCComponent(ApplicationSession):

    def onConnect(self):
        self.join(self.config.realm)

    @coroutine
    def onJoin(self, details):
        def onTicker(*args, **kwargs):
            print('LTCComponent', args, kwargs)

        try:
            yield from self.subscribe(onTicker, channel1)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Could not subscribe to topic:", e)

class XMRComponent(ApplicationSession):

    def onConnect(self):
        self.join(self.config.realm)

    @coroutine
    def onJoin(self, details):
        def onTicker(*args, **kwargs):
            print('XMRComponent', args, kwargs)

        try:
            yield from self.subscribe(onTicker, channel2)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Could not subscribe to topic:", e)

def main():
    runner = ApplicationRunner("wss://api.poloniex.com:443", "realm1", extra={})
    runner.run(LTCComponent)
    runner.run(XMRComponent) # <- is not being called


if __name__ == "__main__":

    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        quit()

    except Exception as e:
        print(time.time(), e)
```

My knowledge of the `autobahn` library is limited, and I'm afraid the documentation isn't improving my situation much. Am I overlooking something here? A function, a parameter, which would enable me to either compound my components or run them both at once?

Perhaps a similar solution as [provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28414302/how-create-a-python-application-with-two-thread-each-which-has-a-autobahn-applic), which implements an alternative `ApplicationRunner` ?

---

Related Topics

[Running two ApplicationSessions in twisted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28414302/how-create-a-python-application-with-two-thread-each-which-has-a-autobahn-applic)

[Running Autobahn ApplicationRunner in Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38298548/multiple-thread-with-autobahn-applicationrunner-and-applicationsession)

[Autobahn.wamp.ApplicationSession Source](http://autobahn.ws/python/_modules/autobahn/wamp/protocol.html#ApplicationSession)

[Autobahn.wamp.Applicationrunner Source](http://autobahn.ws/python/_modules/autobahn/asyncio/wamp.html#ApplicationRunner)

---

As Requested, the Traceback from @stovfl's answer using `multithreading` code:

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nils/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line     914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/nils/git/tools/gemini_wss/t2.py", line 27, in run
    self.appRunner.run(self.__ApplicationSession)
  File "/home/nils/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/autobahn-    0.14.1-py3.5.egg/autobahn/asyncio/wamp.py", line 143,     in run
    transport_factory = WampWebSocketClientFactory(create,         url=self.url,                 serializers=self.serializers)
  File "/home/nils/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/autobahn-    0.14.1-py3.5.egg/autobahn/asyncio/websocket.py", line     319, in __init__
    WebSocketClientFactory.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nils/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/autobahn-    0.14.1-py3.5.egg/autobahn/asyncio/websocket.py", line     268, in __init__
    self.loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()
  File "/home/nils/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/asyncio/events.py",     line 626, in get_event_loop
    return get_event_loop_policy().get_event_loop()
  File "/home/nils/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/asyncio/events.py",     line 572, in get_event_loop
    % threading.current_thread().name)
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-2'.
Exception in thread Thread-1:
**Same as in Thread-2**
...
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the approach [you linked for twisted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28414302/how-create-a-python-application-with-two-thread-each-which-has-a-autobahn-applic) I managed to get same behaviour with asyncio setting *start_loop=False*

```
import asyncio
from autobahn.asyncio.wamp import ApplicationSession, ApplicationRunner

runner1 = ApplicationRunner(url, realm, extra={'cli_id': 1})
coro1 = runner1.run(MyApplicationSession, start_loop=False)

runner2 = ApplicationRunner(url, realm, extra={'cli_id': 2})
coro2 = runner2.run(MyApplicationSession, start_loop=False)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(coro1)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(coro2)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()

class MyApplicationSession(ApplicationSession):

    def __init__(self, cfg):
        super().__init__(cfg)
        self.cli_id = cfg.extra['cli_id']

   def onJoin(self, details):
        print("session attached", self.cli_id)
```

Answer (score 2):

As I see from the `traceback`, we only reach Step 2 of 4

> From the **asyncio** docs:
>   This module provides infrastructure for writing single-threaded concurrent code using coroutines, multiplexing I/O access over sockets and other resources

So I drop my first proposal using `multithreading`.
I could imagin the following three options:

1. Do it with `multiprocessing` instead of `multithreading`
2. Do it with `coroutine` inside `asyncio loop`
3. Switch between `channels` in `def onJoin(self, details)`

---

Second proposal, first option using `multiprocessing`.
I can start two `asyncio loops`, so `appRunner.run(...)` should work.

You can use **one** `class ApplicationSession` if the `channel` are the only different.
If you need to pass different `class ApplicationSession` add it to the `args=`

```
class __ApplicationSession(ApplicationSession):
        # ...
        try:
            yield from self.subscribe(onTicker, self.config.extra['channel'])
        except Exception as e:
            # ...

import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def ApplicationRunner_process(realm, channel):
        appRunner = ApplicationRunner("wss://api.poloniex.com:443", realm, extra={'channel': channel})
        appRunner.run(__ApplicationSession)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    AppRun = [{'process':None, 'channel':'BTC_LTC'},
              {'process': None, 'channel': 'BTC_XMR'}]

    for app in AppRun:
        app['process'] =  mp.Process(target = ApplicationRunner_process, args = ('realm1', app['channel'] ))
        app['process'].start()
        time.sleep(0.1)

    AppRun[0]['process'].join()
    AppRun[1]['process'].join()
```

Comment: eh, you're right - that sentence didn't make much sense. The `run()` method *does* block. I was referring to the hacky solution of overwriting the signal call and starting a separate event loop in the thread. Probably got lost while editing.

Comment: Unfortunately that still raises the `RuntimeError` for not having a current event loop in the thread.

Comment: We're very close - the code runs, but there appears to be an error mesage when I try to hook into the second channel. `2017-03-16T08:07:33 wamp.error.not_authorized: internal error: realm auto-activation not yet implemented` is the response to that. Is that a code issue, or an API issue? Googling yielded no meaningful result.

Comment: As I don't check the meaning of `realm` this could be that i use a different `realm` in my example. Try `realm1` for both.

Comment: ach crud, I didn't even pay attention to that - You're right. Poloniex only has a single realm. Cheers, man! This works.

Comment: Updated my Answer to cover this. Please comment did you use **one** `class ApplicationSession` or **different**?

Comment: Just one class definition for `ApplicationSession`. Using the `extras` attribute worked just fine.